# GCC says the file doesn't exists, but it does

Tags: file, gcc

So, I'm trying to convert my kernel.c file into a object file (.o), but when I try using this command line (gcc -c kernel.c -o kernel.o) it says that the file (kernel.c, duh.) doesn't exist. It's in the same directory and it is indeed spelled right and it is also a .c file. Any help?

Comment: Do you have read access to it?

Comment: Can't you just do `gcc -c kernel.c` to get `kernel.o`

Comment: I fixed it by using a different compiler.

Comment: Never mind, it didn't work. I guess the one I got was glitched and it turned out to be corrupted, giving me another error.